# Failure to marshal argument(s) exception and org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure to marshal argument(s)

Tags: java, jboss

I am using JBOSS 7.1.1 in Clustered mode and the  data which an application is trying to store inside the HttpSession is also  marked as "java.io.Serializable".But still I am getting the org.infispan.commons.CacheException,Along with this failure to marshall arguments is also recorded.Please suggest me a way to fix this out.

Comment: At least within the conglemerates of your object aggregation, one is not serializable. Just go through your object hierarchy. It may be an implicit reference which you may be overlooking

Comment: Thanks Mr.maress for helping me out..since I am a newcomer to this field can you please elaborate on your above comment ,may be with an example if possible.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? If so please paste it.